# civicCRM hangs. Crashes site

Tags: installation

php5.5/Mysql5.6

latest wordpress

civiCRM 4.6

host: ganfi.net

Install but then hangs, and hangs & eventually crashes site

FIX??

Comment: Could you provide some more information? Any error messages? Error logs?

Comment: ganfi.net doesn't resolve. I wouldn't waste too much time on a server that doesn't finish an install, there are likely multiple issues.

Answer (score 1):

Look for error message in civicrm error log

.../wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog

where you will get more details of the error

If you don't have any error message in civicrm logs look for PHP error logs where you will find it

refer: https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Debugging+for+developers

I guess this helps!!!